# Error in setter in class maximum recursion depth

Tags: python

My friends, as far as I check my syntax code is correct, comrades, thank you for your help

My code:

```
class person:
   def __init__(self,name,family):
       self.name = name
       self.family = family
   @property
   def fullname(self):
      return f"{self.name} {self.family}"

class user(person):
       def __init__(self,name,family,age):
            super().__init__(name,family)
            self.age = age  
       @property
       def age(self):
              return self.age
       @age.setter
       def age(self,age_new):
              self.age = age_new

emanuel = user("emanuel","victor",15)

print(emanuel.fullname)

print(emanuel.age)

emanuel.age = 20

print(emanuel.age)
```

---

Error:
Comrades, I am training and I get a lot of errors, but what can I really do about this one?

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 20, in <module>
    emanuel = user("emanuel","victor",15)
  File "main.py", line 12, in __init__
    self.age = age  
  File "main.py", line 18, in age
    self.age = age_new
  File "main.py", line 18, in age
    self.age = age_new
  File "main.py", line 18, in age
    self.age = age_new
  [Previous line repeated 994 more times]
RecursionError: maximum recursion depth exceeded
```

Comment: For good style in Python code, capitalise the class names in CamelCase style. Then they are visibly different from methods, functions and variables which use snake_case style (all lower case, with underscores between words).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to use an attribute with a different name to your property.  Otherwise when you try to set `self.age` from inside the setter method, the setter calls itself.

Try this instead:

```py
class User(Person):
    def __init__(self, name, family,age):
        super().__init__(name, family)
        self._age = age  
    
    @property
    def age(self):
        return self._age
    
    @age.setter
    def age(self, age_new):
        self._age = age_new
```